# Remove seconds from a clock

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to do some research on how to do this but still no luck. Basically, I have a clock on a 12 hour format that shows automatically on page load. What I'm trying to do here is that how will I be able to change the clock format to 24 hour by using an AddEventLister? Would also like to add another AddEventListener that removes the seconds from it. Here's my code

```js
function myClock() {
  let date = new Date(); 
  let hh = date.getHours();
  let mm = date.getMinutes();
  let ss = date.getSeconds();
  let session = "AM";

  if(hh == 0){
      hh = 12;
  }
  if(hh > 12){
      hh = hh - 12;
      session = "PM";
   }

   hh = (hh < 10) ? "0" + hh : hh;
   mm = (mm < 10) ? "0" + mm : mm;
   ss = (ss < 10) ? "0" + ss : ss;
   
   let time = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + " " + session;

  document.getElementById("time-now").innerText = time; 
  var t = setTimeout(function(){myClock()}, 1000); 
 
}
myClock();
```

```html
<span id="time-now"></span>
```

Comment: I think you're complicating things by getting current time and recreating the hh:mm:ss string

Comment: Remove lines with `ss` and all `if` statements. Then add `if (hh === 24) {hh=0}` on this line: `let time = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + " " + session;` remove `+ ":" + ss + " " + session;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic compressed (and edge-case tested) using `.toLocaleTimeString()`. With it, [you can specify a locale and several formatting options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), including 24-hour clock....

```js
function myClock(locale) {
  const date = new Date(); 
  const time = date.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour12: false })
  document.getElementById("time-now").innerText = time; 
  setTimeout(() => myClock(locale), 1000); 
}
// US just for example
myClock('en-US');
```

```html
<span id="time-now"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const  myClock=(locale)=> {
  const date = new Date(); 
  const time = date.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour12: false 
   })
  document.getElementById("time-now").innerText = time; 
  setTimeout(() => myClock(locale), 1000); 
}
// US just for example
myClock('en-US');
```

Comment: I guess I'll interpret this nearly exact copy of my answer as an endorsement.